# Half-Bridge inverter with IR2110, high side control signal diverges

Tags: power, inverter, igbt

I am designing a single-phase half-bridge inverter with SPWM modulation on LTSpice, the SPWM control signal is 10 kHz and the reference sine wave is 50 Hz.

Initially the simulation seems to work, but after about 7 ms the HO (high output) PIN of IR2110 starts to diverge, and consequently the inverter stops working.

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

Gate control voltage waveform diverging (HO_1):

[image: ho_divergenge]

Pin V_S:

[image]

Output AC waveform (detected between C3 and C4) reaching it's limit due to divergence:

[image: AC]

SPWM Generation:

[image: pwmgeneration]

Components such as capacitors were sized with the support of the IR2110 manufacturer's application note. The schematic follows the same connections as in the paper.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the significance of HO alone? Surely HO-VS (U2 Vge) would be of interest. What is I(L1)?

Comment: Thank you Tim, i updated the question

Comment: Try some load resistance across C4 and give the inductor some DC resistance

Comment: Plot HO relative to Vs please.

Comment: it works. Thank you

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681652/half-bridge-inverter-with-ir2110-controller-stops-working-almost-immediately) your question; use the edit button when you need to edit.